# WordPress uploads rsync file ownership issues

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync

I'm running a LEMP stack. Nginx is running as `www-data` user.

It's running a WordPress installation. Every time I upload something the uploaded files belong to `www-data` as expected.

I'm trying to rsync my uploads folder onto the server sshing in as the `deploy` user.

BUT, unless I run `sudo chown -R deploy:deploy uploads` on the server to change ownership I have ownership issues and the rsync fails.

Is there any way to avoid this kind of issue? I come across it all the time! Can both users be added to the same group? I'm definitely a rookie when it comes to understanding users and groups. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the rsync commando you are using? When using a/o/p arguments it tries to preserve ownership, in which case it might fail because the user is differently on the server.

Comment: Sure... here is the command `/usr/bin/env rsync -avz -e "ssh -p 12345" deploy@staging.example.com:/var/www/html/shared/web/app/uploads/ web/app/uploads/`